# Nested Ajax Call, Inner call runs twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bytestream

I'm new in MVC, I have two Call Ajax, want to use result of the first call in a second call, but the results comes back two times. second call ajax shows image of one of the results in first call ajax.
this is my action in the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMaterialsPic(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Pic = db.MaterialPictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.EntityId == id)?.Id;
    var  picFiles = db.MaterialPictures.Where(p => p.EntityId == id).Select(p => new {p.EntityId,p.Id,p.SystemFile}).FirstOrDefault();

    if (picFiles?.SystemFile != null)
        ViewBag.PicFile = Convert.ToBase64String(picFiles.SystemFile);

    return Json(picFiles,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this is my call ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'GetMaterials',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { id: radioselect },
            success: function (materials) {
                $("#MaterialId").html("");
                $.each(materials, function (i, value) {

                    var Id=value.MaterialId;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'GetMaterialsPic',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: { id: Id },
                        success: function (picFiles, status, jqXhr) {
                            var data = '@(ViewBag.PicFile)';
                            $("#MaterialId").append(
                $('<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  name="MaterialsId" value="' + value.Name + '" style="position: inherit;margin-left: 20px;" />' + value.Name + ' </label><img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" style="display: inline;">'));

                        },
                        error: function (jqXhr, status, errorMsg) {
                            $("#MaterialId").append(
                                             $('<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  name="MaterialsId" value="' + value.Name + '" style="position: inherit;margin-left: 20px;" />' + value.Name + ' </label> <img class="img-null" alt="عکس" style="display: inline;">'));
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is your first ajax call returning?

Comment: reurn materialname and twic call return image of one material

Comment: its in each so you are calling that many times as loop iterates.

Comment: Please,help me..

Comment: Can you update your question with response of first ajax call?

Comment: I have to use Id of material for get it's image... Do you have any Idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: my first call ajax by itself is correct run,but when use second call ajax is not correctly runed

Comment: Not a lot of your code makes sense. Your setting `ViewBag` properties in your controller which you never use (you returning a `JsonResult`, not html so they are ignored). Your `var data = '@(ViewBag.PicFile)';` only returns the initial value of `ViewBag.PicFile` - i.e. its value when the page is first rendered.

Comment: why my inner call ajax runs twice ?

Comment: Do you have any idea for resolve my problem?